# Comparing 2 files first column and if matches the matched records should be placed in a newfile

Tags: shell, unix

I have 2 files.

```
File 1
abc,116,39.1,,2014-01-15,0,0
def,7156,49.1,,2014-01-15,0,0
ghi,1234,22.1,,2014-01-15,0,0
jkl,5678,10.2,,2014-01-15,0,0

File 2:
abc,116,59.1,,2014-01-15,0,0
def,7156,49.1,39.1,2014-01-15,0,0
```

Desired o/p :
compare the first 2 column from file2 to file1. The matched records from both the files should place in a new file in the below format.

```
abc,116,39.1,,2014-01-15,0,0
abc,116,59.1,,2014-01-15,0,0
def,7156,49.1,,2014-01-15,0,0
def,7156,49.1,39.1,2014-01-15,0,0
```

Please help on this.

Comment: [Please see this link on how to ask good questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Specify exactly what fields should go into the matched records. Should all output fields be taken from File 2, or just the 3rd? What if the other fields don't match?

Comment: I'd use [tag:awk]. Search for `[awk] "NR==FNR"`, and you'll find tons of examples about exactly this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. i have verified many examples and the desired o/p in the file3 rows are  different. in Many examples are showing the identical rows from 1 file was moved to third file. but i need both files record.  please help.

Comment: Thanks Mklement. 
1. Compare the first 2 column (abc,116) from file 2 and compare the File 1.  
2. If matched,  then File 1 matched row moved to File3 
abc,116,39.1,,2014-01-15,0,0
and also the same matched column row from File has to move to file 3.

Eg o/p :

File 3:

abc,116,39.1,,2014-01-15,0,0 --- > From File1
abc,116,59.1,,2014-01-15,0,0 ----> From File2

Answer (score 1):

```
while read line 
do 
    head=$(echo $line |cut -d , -f 1)
    grep "^"$head file1  >> file3
    echo $line >> file3
done < file2
```